# How to choose the appropriate public (i, m) and private (j, m) keys?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

I studied some encryption and decryption and I have found some very interesting problem to solve on the internet. I hope I am writing to right site - there are so many in StackExchange otherwise I hope some moderator will move it.

So, how to choose the appropriate public lets say `(i, m)` and private `(j, m)` keys which could be subsequently used to (de)encrypt in RSA when there are primes lets say `p = 17` and `q = 5`?

I tried something like:

```
17*5=85

(17-1)*(5-1)=64
```

`64` should be magic number but still do not know what to do next, can anyone help me here?
 I would really appreciate how to choose and in which way these keys ...

Comment: I assume you mean keys, not kies?

Comment: Yes sorry .. Corrected

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Your last sentence doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $m = pq$ (85) is the modulus, and the number you computed (64) is $\phi(m)$. Now we must choose the exponents ($i$ for public, $j$ for secret? , weird notation) in such a way that $ij = 1$ modulo $\phi(m)$. In fact we can work modulo 16 if we like, because that is the least common multiple of $p-1$ and $q-1$. So if we choose $i = 3$, we choose $j=11$, as $33 \equiv 1 \mod 16$. Or $i=11$, $j=3$, this is symmetrical. Or we could choose $i = 5$ and then $j=13$ works, or vice versa again.

Then encryption of a number smaller than $m$ is exponentiation to the power $i$, modulo $m$ and decryption is exponentiation to the power $j$, modulo $m$.

Of course these numbers are way too small to provide any security, but that's the general idea.

Comment: How did you get the number 16 from 64? I thought it must be always 64 no metter what. And how did you get the i,j numbers from that exactly?

Comment: We can use either one, both work. Either $(p-1)(q-1)$ or the least common multiple of $(p-1)$ and $q-1$. And you just pick _any_ $i$ that has an inverse $j$ modulo that number.

Comment: Ok thank you I uderstand now why I can choose number 16 but still I do not know how to get the keys - which mechanism to use to get them? Or just guessing?? What if I need bigger numbers?

Comment: Mostly people choose some $i$ that has no divisors in common with $\phi(m)$ (in this case 64), and this is easy to check (Euclid's algorithm) and then $j$ is its inverse (also found by the (extended) Euclidean algorithm). We can choose any such $i$ (and keep its inverse $j$ secret). Often $i=3$ or $i=2^{16}+1$ is chosen, but we need not do that. It's the same for bigger numbers.

Comment: Question is answered thank you, still do not know how exactly to get the I and J numbers, though. But never mind - for me it would be like step-by-step manual only works :) but thank you anyway.